# Which android devices expose wide-angle camera to developers?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I know that

> “The wide angle camera is very manufacturer and device specific, i.e.
> some manufacturers choose to expose wide angle cameras to developers
> and some don’t. Even those that expose the wide angle only do so on
> certain devices.”

and

> “Some devices indeed do so today in an non-determinstic manner.”

But do you know examples of devices that expose wide angle cameras to developers ?
I know for example that **I can use** the wide-angle camera for my applications in these devices:

- Samsung Galaxy S10
- Huawei P30 pro

And **I CAN'T** use the wide-angle camera in these devices:

- Samsung A50
- Samsung A40
- Google Pixel 4

Could you help me enlarge this list ?
Thanks

Comment: This seems better suited for github or a wiki rather than a StackOverflow question.